# Regular expression for line breaks,new line & carriage returns

Tags: php

I want to replace "
,\r,\n" these characters & break tag from a string. I try to build following regular expression but failed.

```
$strText = preg_replace( '/[^\r|\n]|<br\W*?\/>/', ' ', $strText );
```

For eg:-

```
$strtext = 'Test111<br>222<br/>333\r444\n555';
Expected = 'Test111 222 333 444 555';
```

Comment: Why would you want to capture `\r` by itself? `\r\n` is a carriage return and line break (windows style), but the `\r` is just the carriage return (imagine going back to the start of the line and setting the cursor there, but not inserting a new line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
$strText = 'Test111<br>222<br/>333\r444\n555';
$strText = preg_replace('/(<br\/*>|\\\r|\\\n)/', ' ', $strText);

var_dump($strText); //string(23) "Test111 222 333 444 555"
```

**demo:** https://ideone.com/xCqQsj

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array

```
$strText = preg_replace( [
    "/[\r\n]/",    //New Lines
    "/<br[^>]*>/", //Break tags
    "/\s{2,}/"     //Run-on spaces
  ], " ", $strText );
```

When you use an array the replacements are done in order, so we can put `\s{2,}` 2 or more spaces at the end to get any run-on spaces.